# How to save a QPixmap Object to a file?

Tags: qt, qpixmap

I'm having trouble reading and writing QByteArray data to a file.

My goal is to save QPixmap data into a QByteArray and save that QByteArray to a file (with the ability to read this QByteArray back from the file and into a QPixmap). I want to use following code from the QPixmap documentation:

```
     QPixmap pixmap(<image path>);  
     QByteArray bytes;
     QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
     buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
     pixmap.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes pixmap into bytes in PNG format
```

After writing the buffer to a file, I want to be able to retrieve the QByteArray and load it back into a QPixmap using the QPixmap::loadFromData() function.

Please let me know if any further clarification is needed (I'm open to alternative approaches as well, I just need to be able to read and write the QPixmap to a file! :) );

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That seemed like a really long way to go about doing it (but your comment better explains):

For writing:

```
QFile file("yourFile.png");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
pixmap.save(&file, "PNG");
```

For reading:

```
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.load("yourFile.png");
```

`QBuffer` is great when you need a `QIODevice` and want to keep it in memory, but if you're actually going out to disk, then it's an unnecessary middle step.

**EDIT:**

To write pixmaps, and other things, to a single file I'd recommend that you use [QDataStream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html).

For writing:

```
QFile file("outfile.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&file);
out << QString("almost any qt value object")
    << yourQPixMap << yourQList /* << etc. */;
```

Then, you can do similarly for reading:

```
QFile file("infile.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream in(&file);
in >> firstQString >> yourQPixmap >> yourList /* >> etc. */;
```

You'll need to make sure that you read in the same objects as you wrote them out.  In order to save yourself future compatibility headaches, set the QDataStream version explicitly.

Comment: This solution is great but I need to be able to save multiple image data along with text to a single file. For example, my file would contain

picture 1 title, picture 1 info... etc
<Associated QPixmap data>

picture 2 title, picture 2 info... etc 
<Associated QPixmap data>

Any suggestions?